# Does Cryo damage ignore damage resistance in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Is cryo damage reduced by energy resistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.
The cryolator does energy damage, so it is mitigated by energy resistance.

Long answer: Yes, but the bonus damage is [applied quite awkwardly](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3tjngh/useful_info_inside_on_games_mechanics_after_a_lot/).